# command line tool to reserve code high light in output file?

Tags: command-line, syntax-highlighting

For example, when using ack to search code in source files, the output is high lighted. But if you pipe the output into a local file, you lose the code high light. Do we have a command line tool to reserve it?

To understand what I mean:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/koehlma/jaspy
$ cd jaspy/
$ ack func ./* # you see the high light for each match
$ ack func ./* > output.txt
$ cat output.txt # you don't see the high light
```

Comment: If you `cat` that file, the color output should still be there, no?

Comment: @pfnuesel no, not there. The syntax in output file is totally messed up

Comment: Can you show some output?

Comment: @pfnuesel question updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ack` does something smiliar to `grep`. When it puts it text to a terminal, it will spit the results out in color. If the output is redirected to a file, the matches do not get colorized.

You can override these heuristics with the options `--color` and `--nocolor`.

Check `man 1 ack` for more details.